# R Rblpapi subscribe( ) - multiple securities

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to distinguish one security from another in the response to a subscribe request in the Rblpapi package?

```
secs <- c("RXU6 Comdty", "TYU6 Comdty", "SHSZ300 INDEX")
flds <- c("LAST_PRICE")
subscribe(secs,flds, fun = parseResponse)

parseResponse <- function (x) {
   if (x$event.type == "SUBSCRIPTION_DATA") {
      s <- as.character(x$data$TRADE_UPDATE_STAMP_RT)
      if (!is.null(s)) {
            if (length(s)>0) {
                  ts <- as.POSIXct(s)
                  if ((ts > beg.time) & (ts < end.time)) {
                      print(x$data$EVENT_TIME)
                      print(x$data$LAST_PRICE)
                  }
            }
      }
   }
}

[1] 132.7188
[1] "15:27:16"
[1] 166.15
[1] "15:27:16"
[1] 166.15
[1] "15:27:16"
[1] 166.15
[1] "15:27:16"
[1] 132.7344
```

I need a way to know 132.7344 corresponds to secs[2] and 166.15 secs[1] but I can't see any field in the object x$data which does this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to take a look at the result object from the `subscribe` function is:

```
subscribe(securities=c("AAPL US Equity"),
          fields=c("LAST_PRICE"),
          fun=function(x) print(str(x)))
```

From there you can work your way into the data:

```
subscribe(securities=c("AAPL US Equity", "INTC US Equity"),
          fields=c("LAST_PRICE","BID","ASK"),
          fun=function(x) {
            if (!is.null(x$data$MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE) && x$data$MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE == "TRADE" && exists("LAST_PRICE", where = x$data)) {
              print(data.frame(Ticker = x$topic, DateTime = x$data$TRADE_UPDATE_STAMP_RT, Trade = x$data$LAST_PRICE))
            }
          })
```

The data can be processed or stored directly using the FUN argument of subscribe.